# Don't know how to select ID of a row with maximal negative date difference

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I am trying to get the row with maximal negative date difference ( `date - Now()` for example ) from a table.

Something like this ( pseudo code ):

```
SELECT ID, MAX( DateDiff("d", Now(), myDate) ) AS [test] FROM myTable
    WHERE test < 0;
```

The result would be something like this:

```
ID | test
 1 |  -15
```

*I have tried to solve this on my own but have failed. I do not even know how to phrase the search question on Google, so Internet can not help me. I am just stuck.*

NOTE:

Maximal negative number example: between -10 and -125, result should be -10.

### EDIT:

Trying out on my own, I was able to come close:

```
SELECT MAX( DateDiff("d", myDate, Now()) as [test] from myTable
    WHERE DateDiff("d", myDate, Now() < 0;
```

It returns correct date difference, but when I try to add ID as well, it returns date difference for all the rows. I can not get single value.

Comment: @HansUp: *For example given -10 and -15, which is the one you want returned?* -10

Comment: OK, and you want to compute such a `Max` value for each distinct `ID` ... correct?  If so, you need a `GROUP BY` query.

Comment: @HansUp: No, I just need the ID of the row that has maximal negative date difference. I am not interested in other rows, just the one with minimal value.

Comment: Then is `ID` the primary key of `myTable`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
SELECT TOP 1
    ID,
    DateDiff('d', Now(), myDate) AS [test]
FROM myTable
WHERE Now() > myDate
ORDER BY 2 DESC;
```

Comment: The only reason I did not accept is that he was first. Upvoted. Thank you.

Comment: *Notice you accepted an answer with a `DateDiff` expression which is not valid in Access.* I have tried his query and it worked. Can you clarify? *And its WHERE clause will force a full table scan.* This was the reason to accept your answer and unaccept his. I really need high performance for the app I am coding. Thank you for pointing it out. Best regards.

Comment: In my testing, a query with `DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate)` asks me to supply a value for a parameter named `Day`.  Don't you see the same thing?  The first `DateDiff` argument is supposed to be a string value; you want `'d'`.

Comment: `WHERE Now() > myDate` can make use of an index on `myDate`, so the db engine can efficiently identify the qualifying rows.  `WHERE DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate) < 0` requires that function to be run again for every row of the table in order to identify which rows qualify --- that means a full table scan.

Comment: *In my testing, a query with DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate) asks me to supply a value for a parameter named Day.* I have substituted it with `'"d"` so I completely missed your point. At the time I wrote the post/tested answers it was 7 AM ad I haven't slept so I missed it. Good catch. Again, performance is very important to me which is the reason I accepted your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ORDER BY` and `TOP 1`.
Something like this.

```
SELECT TOP 1 ID, myDate, DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate) AS [test]
FROM myTable
WHERE DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate) < 0
ORDER BY DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate) DESC -- min differenz
-- ORDER BY DateDiff(Day, now(), myDate) ASC -- max differenz
```

Comment: I apologize for unaccepting your answer. The reason I did it was that other answer offers me higher performance, and that is really crucial for the application I am developing. Again I apologize, please do not hold that against me. Best regards.